# object based and object oriented language

Tags: oop

well i am having lots of question regarding to the desired topic,well its better to be short here.

1> C# is object oriented or object based

2> java is object oriented or object based

as per my knowledge c# is object oriented and java is object based,if it is true then what makes java to be oriented not object oriented.

Comment: It seems to me that "object oriented" and "object based" are synonyms in most contexts. You may need to provide definitions of the terms to clarify the question.

Comment: there is nothing like what u have written,the question is perfectly right

Comment: before giving negative points i think u shud have proper knowledge of the question as well knowledge of answer

Comment: As evidenced by the comment exchange below, you're not looking for a real answer to this question. Thus, I'm voting to close.

Comment: i really dont have any prob if u r closing the post,just like to give u a simple sugassition......half knowledge is dangerous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object based programming paradigm makes use of all the features of object oriented programming except for `inheritance`. For example `JavaScript` is object based whereas `Java` is object oriented.

Although it is common to use these two terms mutually exclusively, practically speaking, an `object oriented` language is also `object based` but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Both C# and Java are [object-oriented languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming_language).

Generally, a language is regarded as ["object-based"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-based_languages) when it lacks support for certain central features of a truly object-oriented language, namely inheritance and polymorphism. A good example of an object-based language is VB 6 (the pre-.NET version). It was *based* on objects, but it did not support either inheritance or polymorphism, making it impossible to regard as a truly object-oriented language.

Comment: but java does not support operator overloding,which is a part of polymorphism

Comment: @slash shogdhe: Operator overloading is not a property of Object Orientation. It just makes a lot of sense there.

Comment: @slash: I don't see how operator overloading is part of polymorphism. It is not necessarily even part of an object-oriented paradigm, and some would even go so far as to argue that overloading is anti-OO. More to the point, there's no real definition of what a "pure" object-oriented language looks like. Why ask the question if you think you already know the answer?

Comment: http://www.google.com/Top/Computers/Programming/Languages/Object-Oriented/Pure/ Can u plz check the link above

Comment: @slash: Again, why ask a question if you are already convinced of the answer? No, I don't consider "Google Directory" an authoritative source. Objective-C doesn't support operator overloading, either. Do you think this makes it not an object-oriented language?

Comment: well overloading and overriding is the part of polymorphsim,for sure

Comment: well i dont have any idea aout objective c,question is related to c# and java

Comment: @slash: "Objective-C is a reflective, object-oriented programming language that adds Smalltalk-style messaging to the C programming language." ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C))

Comment: y u r pushing the question out of track

Comment: @slash: Wow... What the heck do you want from me? You asked a question, to which I provided an answer. You apparently already "knew" the answer, so you posted a comment disagreeing. I explained that your central assumption (operator overloading is necessary for a language to be truly OO) is incorrect. When pressed for further explanation, I provided an example of a language that is generally regarded as object-oriented, but does not support operator overloading. I don't know if you are being intentionally obnoxious, or if you're really struggling to understand the conversation.

Comment: @slash: Cody gave you a perfect and correct answer to your original question. It seems you think that some details like Operator Overloading are required parts of OOP, but that's not strictly the case. The point is whether the language supports objects as first class citizens (object oriented) or whether it is merely able to cope with objects a little (object based), like Visual BASIC.

Comment: i dont know the correct answer,thats y i have posted the question.well pollymorphsim(operotor overloadig,method overloading,method overriding ) is the main part of oops.one more important point is all premitive types shud be object.ok there are lots of other thing thats makes a language to be oops.if u search for java then u will find its not pure oops,i just like to know the reason for this.

Comment: http://www.jvoegele.com/software/langcomp.html its explain java and c# both are not oops,there again comes a prob,according to the link all premitivtes type are not object in c# which is wrong and i dont know about java

Comment: there is one more thing language which supports static keyword are not considered to be oops becoz u can not create the object of static class.whic is again i think is wrong becoz compiler use to create the object of static class but they are not stored in object heap ,thay are stored in loader heap(which is also known as high frequency heap).difference is loader heap is not handled by GC but object heap is handeled by gc

Comment: @slash: So, what are you asking? You've just given like 4 reasons why you think *neither* Java nor C# are fully object-oriented languages. Unfortunately, that's not a question. Get a blog and post on there instead. If you want to know why both of these languages are generally considered to be object-oriented, despite the objections you've just given, see my answer above. Whether a language is "fully" or "purely" object-oriented is a subjective issue because there's no definition for either of the terms.

Comment: i am not from java,thats y i have posted the question.

Comment: @slashshogdhe A language does not have to support operator-overloading to be considered OO. As stated earlier, many would even consider operator-overloading to go against OO principles. It's important to note the difference between operator-overloading and method-overloading/overriding.    Method over-loading is a very different concept.

Comment: @slashshogdhe The reason that Java is considered OO, is that it supports "abstract data types", algebraic data types, encapsulated state, as well as inheritance. It largely relies on encapsulation, which is a cornerstone of what defines a language as OO.